# Getting PHP variables from .txt file and discarding characters

Tags: php, variables

I know the pure basics of PHP, and I need help converting text into variables from a .txt file.

The text inside the .txt file (lets call it 'info.txt') is in a single line as follows:

```
Robert | 21 | male | japanesse |
```

So what I need is to convert the information in variables as follows:

```
<?php
   $name = 'Robert';
   $age = '21';
   $sex = 'male';
   $nacionality = 'japanesse';
?>
```

Note that I want to discard the '|' between every data.

How could I do that using PHP? Using arrays? How?

Comment: When using `explode()` as your answers recommend, it will probably be best to use `explode(" | "...` instead of `explode("|"...` so your strings will not have extra spaces. If the number of spaces between the strings and the separators is not consistent, it may require something a little more complex.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$file_content = file_get_contents($fileName);
list($name, $age, $sex, $nationality) = explode("|", $file_content);
echo "Hello ". $name;
```

Use explode to get information in an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) & [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) functions

```
$data = file_get_contents('info.txt');
$parsedData = explode("|", $data);
var_dump($parsedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "explode" a string in PHP using the [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) function. You can also use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) to get the contents of a file.  Assuming that the format of the file is always consistent, you can couple [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) with [`list`](http://php.net/list) to assign directly to your variables.

For example

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents("file.txt");

$lines = explode("\n", $string);

list($name, $age, $sex, $nationality) = explode("|", $lines[0]);
```

This reads the contents of "file.txt" into an array, and then assigns the first line's contents to the variables `$name`, `$age`, `$sex`, `$nationality`

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
//Step 1
$content = file_get_contents('info.txt');

//Step 2
$info = explode('|', $content);

//Step 3
$name =         $info[0];
$age  =         $info[1];
$sex  =         $info[2];
$nationality =  $info[3];
```

## Explaination

1. First load the contents in `info.txt` in a variable using the
   [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function:

   ```
   $content = file_get_contents('info.txt');
   ```
2. Second, break up the content into little pieces based on the `|` character using the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function. The broken bits will be stored in an array.

   ```
   $info = explode('|', $content);
   ```
3. Now assign each value in the array from step 2 to a variable

   ```
   $name =         $info[0];
   $age  =         $info[1];
   $sex  =         $info[2];
   $nationality =  $info[3];
   ```

   you can do this step in a shorter way using the [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function as shown in the other answers!

---

**Ultra short, one line code for fun**

```
list($name, $age, $sex, $nationality) = explode("|", file_get_contents("file.txt"));
```